# warning: setlocale: LC_ALL: cannot change locale (C.UTF-8) while using Cloud9 and Openshift

Tags: git, ssh, openshift, locale, cloud9-ide

I am using Openshift to host my website/application, and using Cloud 9 as an online IDE to code the website in. Everytime I pushed code to the openshift git repo, or if I SSH'ed into openshift from Cloud9, I kept getting the following error:

> warning: setlocale: LC_ALL: cannot change locale (C.UTF-8)

The error would be intermingled with the git command or SSH login completing successfully, so it was more annoying rather than causing issue.

Searched and searched and finally found a solution combining two different approaches. See answer below.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On Cloud9, run the following commands:

```
sudo locale-gen “en_US.UTF-8”

sudo dpkg-reconfigure locales
```

Then (still on cloud9), assuming you have already done rhc setup to link to your OpenShift account, do the following:

```
rhc env-set -a <app_name> LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8
```

Then either try a git push, or ssh into openshift, and you should no longer see the errors.

I’m not entirely sure if the sudo locale-gen and dpkg commands actually helped, but I know the moment I got to the rhc env set command it worked and removed the issue.

You should be able to change the locale to something that suits you, but I did not find I needed to for my needs.

Sources:

- https://askubuntu.com/questions/162391/how-do-i-fix-my-locale-issue
- https://forums.openshift.com/how-to-set-system-language-and-locale

Comment: I get this error whenever I SSH from c9 into my host's server.  If I run the first two commands, it seems to work.  But then I run `locale`, and don't see `en_US` anywhere.  I'm not using rhc... do you have any insights?